# Mvc 5.1 MissingMethodException System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I'm update my MVC5 project to MVC5.1 and now have exception on route dictionary:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

stack trace:

```
{"Method not found: 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached(System.Object)'."}

at System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.CreateRouteValueDictionaryUncached(Object values)
at System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.IgnoreRoute(RouteCollection routes, String url, Object constraints)
at System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.IgnoreRoute(RouteCollection routes, String url)
at WebApplication1.RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) in c:\Users\aivanov\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\App_Start\RouteConfig.cs:line 14
at WebApplication1.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in c:\Users\aivanov\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Global.asax.cs:line 17
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the References i found that **System.Web.WebPages.dll** version **3.0.11001.0** shows this type of error, but when i replace it with **System.Web.WebPages.dll** version **3.0.20129.0** it works. So Simply you should delete the old one from refrences and download the other version and than **clean solution**, **rebuild** and it will work.

Comment: Where do you download that version?

Comment: I only needed to do Clean Solution and problem solved itself.

Comment: When you use nuget.exe from console "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.1.1" will download System.Web.WebPages.dll as well.

Comment: cansomeone please tell me as to how to download a different version of that `dll` once removed.

Answer (score 1):

In my case helped deleting  files in temporary folder "C:\Users{yourprofilename}\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\"

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have a reference to :
using System.Web.Http;  (c)
or
Imports System.Web.Http (vb)

At the top of your RouteConfig  File in App_Start directory.

Other than that, although the title is a bit off topic, you might find what your looking for at this link on MS: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs - Hopefully this will get you going in the right direction!  If you have other details, please let me know and I would be more than happy to continue to try and help!

Hope all is well.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the step suggested by @Leonardo, I also had to add the following to my Web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
    <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"></add>
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the nuget packages for Microsoft Asp.Net MVC and it worked for me. I am not sure but I think this problem occurs after upgrading MVC version. 
So reinstalling nuget package worked.