# Error in test method in mvc for routing unit test

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, routes

I am creating a test project in MVC for testing routes.

I am getting this error

```
Test Name:  RouteWithControllerNoActionNoId
Test FullName:  test.Web.Tests.Routing.TestRoute.RouteWithControllerNoActionNoId
Test Source:    d:\newtest\test.Web.Tests\Routing\TestRoute.cs : line 17
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:06.6382043

Result Message: 
Test method test.Web.Tests.Routing.TestRoute.RouteWithControllerNoActionNoId threw exception: 
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary        System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached(System.Object)'.
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.CreateRouteValueDictionaryUncached(Object values)
at System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.IgnoreRoute(RouteCollection routes, String url, Object constraints)
at System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.IgnoreRoute(RouteCollection routes, String url)
at test.Web.RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) in d:\newtest\test.Web\App_Start\RouteConfig.cs:line 15
at test.Wesb.Tests.Routing.TestRoute.RouteWithControllerNoActionNoId() in d:\newtest\test.Web.Tests\Routing\TestRoute.cs:line 21
```

This is my sample code

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void RouteWithControllerNoActionNoId()
    {
        // Arrange
        var context = new StubHttpContextForRouting(requestUrl: "~/Home");
        var routes = new RouteCollection();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(routes);

        // Act
        RouteData routeData = routes.GetRouteData(context);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(routeData);
        Assert.AreEqual("Home", routeData.Values["controller"]);
        Assert.AreEqual("Index", routeData.Values["action"]);
        Assert.AreEqual(UrlParameter.Optional, routeData.Values["id"]);
    }
```

I am getting error on this line

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

In my `RouteConfig` file

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See : 
[Mvc 5.1 MissingMethodException System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376261/mvc-5-1-missingmethodexception-system-web-webpages-typehelper-objecttodictionary)

"In the References i found that System.Web.WebPages.dll version 3.0.11001.0 shows this type of error, but when i replace it with System.Web.WebPages.dll version 3.0.20129.0 it works. So Simply you should delete the old one from references and download the other version and than clean solution, rebuild and it will work."