# Method not found error in MVC 5.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am pretty new to asp.net mvc and have started to work in 5.0 version.

This is my `controller`:

```
 public class DimCustomersController : Controller
    {
        private Sales_DW db = new Sales_DW();

        // GET: DimCustomers
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.DimCustomers.ToList());
        }
}
```

And here's my `Index` view:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebAppDisplay.Models.DimCustomer>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomerAltID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomerName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Gender)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerAltID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gender)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CustomerID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.CustomerID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CustomerID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I tried running this `Index` method but got an error:

> Method not found: 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
>   System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached(System.Object)'.

Tried solving my query with [Mvc 5.1 MissingMethodException System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376261/mvc-5-1-missingmethodexception-system-web-webpages-typehelper-objecttodictionary) and other similar links but all efforts went in vain.

The stack trace is as follows:

> [MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
>   System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached(System.Object)'.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.CreateRouteValueDictionaryUncached(Object
>   values) +0
>   System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.IgnoreRoute(RouteCollection
>   routes, String url, Object constraints) +94
>   System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.IgnoreRoute(RouteCollection
>   routes, String url) +7
>   WebAppDisplay.RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) in
>   c:\Users\cc-aakashthakur\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\WebAppDisplay\WebAppDisplay\App_Start\RouteConfig.cs:14 
>   WebAppDisplay.MvcApplication.Application_Start() in
>   c:\Users\cc-aakashthakur\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\WebAppDisplay\WebAppDisplay\Global.asax.cs:17
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Method not found:
>   'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
>   System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached(System.Object)'.]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +9964625
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +339
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Method not found:
>   'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary
>   System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached(System.Object)'.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9946132 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +90
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +261

Can someone please assist.

Comment: What was the url called and what are the registered routes?

Comment: The url is `localhost:61089/DimCustomers` and registered routes are the same default that we get while creating an MVC app in VS.@Nkosi