# Application Error After MVC 5.2.7.0 Upgrade / Telerik Install

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I just recently installed Telerik for ASP.NET MVC and in the process upgraded MVC to 5.2.7. I installed MVC using Nuget. Upon running my project, I receive the following error:

> Method not found: 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached(System.Object)'.

There is another post on this issue, but I have tried the recommendations and haven't found a solution ([Mvc 5.1 MissingMethodException System.Web.WebPages.TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionaryUncached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376261/mvc-5-1-missingmethodexception-system-web-webpages-typehelper-objecttodictionary)).

He mentioned to replace the System.Web.Webpages, which I tried and did not work.

Here is my current Web.config

```
 <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.7.0" newVersion="5.2.7.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I need to keep the new version of MVC in order to use Telerik.

What else can I try? I have tried reinstalling MVC, modifing the Web.WebPages dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else struggling with this same issue, I found out that an older version of System.Web.WebPages was still being referenced through the bin folder. Deleting this version and replacing it with the newest dll fixed my issue.